# How to set proxy using libgit2sharp?

Tags: proxy, clone, libgit2sharp

I use libgit2sharp clone and faced "failed to send request: The operation timed out" when I am using corporate networking.

If I use my own 3G networking, it can clone successfully.

But after I use git config in command line and I can clone repository by command line, I still can't clone repository by the code....

could everyone teach me how to set proxy in the code or how to use this lib in proxy environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Libgit2sharp doesn't allow the use of a proxy by default. You must use another Nuget called "libgit2sharp-proxy-enabled". You can found it here :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/libgit2sharp-proxy-enabled/#dependencies-body-tab

I found this Nuget thanks to this post https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/2043

Don't forget to set the proxy adress in the gitconfig global. Here is an exemple :
git config --global http.https://dev.azure.com.proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx

libgit2sharp-proxy-enabled will use this setting in the gitconfig global to know the proxy adress.